# View properties overlaps each other inside CardView of Gridview

Tags: java, android-layout, gridview, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

I'm using below code to show my Image View inside Gridlayout that is Scrollable vertically. It appears fine inside Design tab but when I run in Device then background image is invisible and when I scroll then view properties overlaps each other.

How it appears inside Design tab
[image]

and when I run on device how it looks
[image]

Below is my gradle code

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nepalpolice.androidgridlayout"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and my layoout contains

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            app:columnCount="2"
            app:rowCount="3"
            app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="14dp"
            >

            <!-- Row 1 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/me_time"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Me"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/family_time"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Family"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/lovely_time"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Lovely"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/team_time"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Team"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/friends"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Friends"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

       </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and my MainActivity contain this

```html
package com.nepalpolice.androidgridlayout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridLayout mainGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);


    }
}
```

Any help will be much much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here at the first LinearLayout as you set `android:layout_height="match_parent">` when the linearlayout within a ScrollView so you have to make it "wrap_content"

Then new design will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        app:columnCount="2"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        app:rowCount="3"
        app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="14dp"
        >

        <!-- Row 1 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/me_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Me"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/family_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Family"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!-- Row 2 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/lovely_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Lovely"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/team_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Team"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!-- Row 2 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/friends"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: okey, I checked it closer, there are many strange things at the design but anyway I removed LinearLayout as I don't see there's any benefit to it ... you can add your background directly to GridLayout
check answer again